# get n:m relationship in typeorm without join table column

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, relationship, typeorm

I'm using typeORM and MySQL.
In TypeORM I made n:m relationship entity like this. I don't use `@ManyToMany` Tag but I use `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany`.
When I get a query, I'd like to exclude the value of the joint table in the middle, but please tell me how to get it.

```
student                     fruit                    taste(student_fruit join table)

id    name                  id    name                id    student_id     fruit_id
1     tom                   1     apple               1     1              1
2     john                  2     grape               2     1              2
3     jack                  3     strawberry          3     3              4
4     alice                 4     watermelon
5     kim                   5     orange
```

```
Student.ts

@Entity()
export class Student{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
  studentId!: number;

@Column()
  name !: string;

@OneToMany(() => Taste, (taste.student))
  taste !: Taste[];
}
```

```
Fruit.ts

@Entity()
export class fruit{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
  fruitId!: number;

@Column()
  name !: string;

@OneToMany(() => Taste, (taste.fruit))
taste !: Taste[];
}
```

```
Taste.ts
@Entity()
export class taste{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
  tasteId!: number;

@ManyToOne(() => Student,(student) => student.taste)
  student !: Student;

@ManyToOne(() => Fruit, (fruit) => fruit.taste)
  fruit !: Fruit;
}
```

**I want to get these result**

```
[
  {
    studentId : 1,
    name : tom
    fruit : [
      {
        fruitId : 1,
        name : apple
      },
      {
        fruitId : 2,
        name : grape
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    studentId : 2,
    name : john
    fruit : []
  },
  {
    studentId : 3,
    name : jack
    fruit : [
      {
        fruitId : 4,
        name : watermelon
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    studentId : 4,
    name : alice
    fruit : []
  },
  {
    studentId : 5,
    name : kim
    fruit : []
  }
]
```

So, using `queryBuilder`, I made this query.

```
StudentRepository.ts

selectStudentFruit(acBusinessNumber: string) {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('student')
      .leftJoin('student.taste', 'taste')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('taste.fruit', 'fruit')
      .select([
        'student.studentId',
        'student.name',
        'fruit.fruitId',
        'fruit.name'
      ])
      .getMany();
  }
```

but I got these result.

```
[
  {
    studentId : 1,
    name : tom
  },
  {
    studentId : 2,
    name : john
  },
  {
    studentId : 1,
    name : tom
  },
  {
    studentId : 1,
    name : tom
  },
{
    studentId : 3,
    name : jack
  },
{
    studentId : 4,
    name : alice
  },
{
    studentId : 5,
    name : kim
  }
]
```

So, I modified Query Like this.

```
selectStudentFruit(acBusinessNumber: string) {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('student')
      .leftJoin('student.taste', 'taste')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('taste.fruit', 'fruit')
      .select([
        'student.studentId',
        'student.name',
        'taste',
        'fruit.fruitId',
        'fruit.name'
      ])
      .getMany();
  }
```

Then, it resulted in this result.

```
[
  {
    studentId : 1,
    name : tom,
    taste : [
      {
        tasteId : 1,
        fruit : {
          fruitId : 1,
          name : apple
        }
      },
      {
        tasteId : 2,
        fruit : {
          fruitId : 2,
          name : grape
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    studentId : 2,
    name : john,
    taste : []
  },
  {
    studentId : 1,
    name : tom,
    taste : [
      {
         tasteId : 3,
         fruit : {
           fruitId : 4,
           name : watermelon
         }
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    studentId : 1,
    name : tom
  },
{
    studentId : 3,
    name : jack
  },
{
    studentId : 4,
    name : alice
  },
{
    studentId : 5,
    name : kim
  }
]
```

I want to take out the 'taste' object.
when I use raw MySql query, I was able to get these results.

```
SELECT student.id,student.name, fruit.id, fruit.name
FROM student
LEFT JOIN fruit 
    ON student.id = taste.student_id
LEFT JOIN fruit
    ON fruit.id = taste.fruit_id;


student_id student_name fruit_id fruit_name
1          tom          1         apple    
1          tom          2         grape    
2          john         null      null
3          jack         4         watermelon
4          alice        null      null
5          kim          null      null
```

When I used raw MySql query, I was able to get this result, but what should I do to get the desired result using TypeOrm?